# jshint error : Redefinition of '_'

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am using the lodash library in my express application.
Whenever I include lodash like:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
```

jshint complains with the error:

```
Redefinition of '_'
```

If I remove the require statement, the application fails and reports that it does not recoginice '_'.

My jshint.rc has the following statement:

```
 "globals": {
    "angular": false,
    "_" : false
  }
```

But this is so that I can include it in the front-end code without jshint complaining.

How do I ask jshint to ignore this error in my node code ?

Comment: in node _ is a reserved word (it's the value from the last instruction evaluated)

Comment: Juhana's comment helped resolve. Basically added the following to the top of the file   /* jshint -W079 */

Comment: @Juhana I'll trust you, but if I remember well in REPL was that. Am I wrong (just for don't do mistakes one more time)?

Comment: @Dario REPLs are allowed to do whatever they like. But just because they assign the last return value to that variable, that doesn’t make it a reserved word.

Answer (score 5):

You have explicitly told jshint that the global variable `_` is **read-only**.

From [the docs](http://jshint.com/docs/):

> **globals**
>
> A directive for telling JSHint about global variables that are defined
>   elsewhere. If value is false (default), JSHint will consider that
>   variable as read-only. Use it together with the undef option.
>
> > /* globals MY_LIB: false */

Since you are using `require` to explicitly define it, I think you can
remove `_` from the `globals` list for JSHint to allow assignment to the variable.

If, however, you are using `_` without explicitly requiring it and expect it to be present in the environment, then you can set `"_" : true` in your `.jshintrc` to still allow assignment to it.

Answer (score 3):

In your jshint.rc you can put: `"no-native-reassign" : 0`, this will disable the native reassign rule, or you can put /*jshint -W079 */ right before the function where you assign _.

When you don't use _ as a global variable you also should remove it from your Globals in jshint. Or set it to true so jshint doesn't see it as readonly.

sources: [JSLint Error explanation](https://jslinterrors.com/redefinition-of-a)